# How to correctly move data from a linked table to the main one in a LINQ query .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

Filtering of the query result using "Where" does not work, in which previously one of the fields was replaced with values from the linked table

I have the Items table with another related table (ItemsAdditionalFiels)

```cs
[Table("Items")]
public class Items : Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Area {get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemsAdditionalFiels> AdditionalFiels { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[Table("ItemsAdditionalFiels")]
public class ItemsAdditionalFiels: Entity
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string AddArea{ get; set; }
}
```

also I have the following query

```cs
IQueryable<Items> query = _context.Set<Items>()
    .Include(i => i.AdditionalFiels);
```

I need that in the case when the city is equal to "London", the values from the Area are replaced by the replaced by the first found AddArea value from the additional properties.

To do this, I wrote the following code

```cs
foreach (var item in query)
{
    if (item.City == "London")
    {
        item.Area = item.AdditionalFiels.FirstOrDefault()?.Location;
    }
}
```

When debugging the code, it is displayed that the necessary data has been successfully replaced.

However, if to try to filter the data, trying to find some value from Area, which was previously replaced by a value from AddArea, it finds nothing.

```cs
var test = query.Where(m => m.Area.Contains("Remote")).ToList(); //nothing was found
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you called `SaveChanges` before filtering data? Because if changes are not saved. in database still old values.

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv I tried, await _context.SaveChangesAsync() doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first get data to list, then Save Changes.

step1:

```
foreach (var item in (await query.ToListAsync()))
{
  if (item.City == "London")
  {
    item.Area = item.AdditionalFiels.FirstOrDefault()?.Location;
  }
}
```

or better:

```
foreach (var item in (await query.Where(x => x.City == "London").ToListAsync()))
{
  item.Area = item.AdditionalFiels.FirstOrDefault()?.Location;
}
```

step2:

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

step3: now you can get data with updated items:

```
var test = query.Where(m => m.Area.Contains("Remote")).ToList();
```

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot use ToList. The result of the operation must be IQueryable<Items> query, because several other methods use the results of this query

Comment: IQueryable<Items> query not changed. only item  Changed in DataBase. then you can get query results with new data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
_context.Entry(item.Area).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You do not have to change state of the Entry. EF automatically tracks changed properties.

Comment: foreach (var item in query)
{
    if (item.City == "London")
    {
        item.Area = item.AdditionalFiels.FirstOrDefault()?.Location;
       _context.Entry(item.Area).State = EntityState.Modified;
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

I tried to do so, but to no avail